# Sharepoint Online No JS Framework, how can redirect to one modern page to another?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, spfx, modern-experience, typescript

I am using:

```
window.location.replace('https://site.sharepoint.com/sites/contosoSite')
```

Also I tried using `href`.

The problem is that when I clicked on the button for redirection the new page is opened nested to the previous page.

```
$('#ok').on('click', () => {    
     window.location.replace('https://condoso.sharepoint.com/sites/contosoSite');
})
```

Comment: Are you trying to do this in SPFx webpart? Or you can use some other webparts on your page to redirect users to another links.

Comment: yes in spfx webpart

Answer (score 1):

Finally, it works, I changed from true to false: on `config/package-solution.json -> "isDomainIsolated": false`.

Comment: You only had to do that? Im having the same issue, but event with isDomainIsolated to false I'm being redirect into a nested page. Any clues what else needs to be in place?

Comment: Answering myself, as the solution deployed with this setting true, it was needed to completely remove the app from the App Catalog and generate a new version of the solution. Reference: https://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2019/04/spfx-isolated-web-parts-with-AadHttpClient.html

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Aris for your sharing, I have the same issue a few months ago, I put the window.location.href just in the render function, it won't redirect and finnally, I also change the isDomainIsolated to false and it solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If your redirection URL is not dynamic then you can create a button like below:

```
<button type="button" onclick="parent.location='<redirection url>'">Click Here</button>
```

Or

```
<button type="button" onclick="location.href='<redirection url>';">Click Here</button>
```

You can find more answer in below link:

[How to create an HTML button that acts like a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link)